# Importing pb.go file in a project

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

How can I import my generated `pb.go` file so I can call the methods in them? I visited all the examples for go and they all seem to import with `github.com/...`

**Example.go**

```
import (
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    chiMiddleware "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/easyCZ/grpc-web-hacker-news/server/hackernews"
    hackernews_pb "github.com/easyCZ/grpc-web-hacker-news/server/proto" // Proto directory.
    "google.golang.org/grpc/grpclog"
    "github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/go/grpcweb"
    "github.com/go-chi/cors"
    "github.com/easyCZ/grpc-web-hacker-news/server/proxy"
    "github.com/easyCZ/grpc-web-hacker-news/server/middleware"
)

func main() {
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer()
    hackernewsService := hackernews.NewHackerNewsService(nil)
    hackernews_pb.RegisterHackerNewsServiceServer(grpcServer, hackernewsService)
    ...
```

**Directory Structure**

```
athena-server
 ┣ proto
 ┃ ┣ athena.pb.go
 ┃ ┗ athena.proto
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┗ server.go
 ┣ .DS_Store
 ┣ docker-compose.yml
 ┣ generated.go
 ┣ go.mod
 ┣ go.sum
 ┣ google_service.json
 ┣ gqlgen.yml
 ┣ models_gen.go
 ┣ resolver.go
 ┣ schema.graphql
 ┗ todo.go
```

**main.go**

```
import (
    "bytes"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/grpclog"

    "github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web/go/grpcweb"

    auth "../proto" // Proto directory but doesn't work.
)
...
```

**Error**

```
cannot find module for path _/Users/xxx/go/src/athena-server/proto
```

I tried all sort both absolute and relative path as well as shifting files around but nothing seems to work.

Comment: "They all seem to import with github.com/..." That's no coincidence: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#ImportPaths

Comment: You cannot import files in Go, only packages. Please read [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/), in particular the part about [imports](https://tour.golang.org/basics/2), and [How to Write Go](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Answer (score 2):

One could do a `go mod init project` and subsequently import go files that reside in some folder, e.g. folder as:

```
import "project/folder"
```

I created several [github projects](https://github.com/030) that contain this structure, e.g. n3dr, bcbsn, go-yq, go-multipart and dip.